# Retrieving data from rows based on condition

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

I have a tab delimited file of 10 columns and 200 rows:

```
a  b  1  0  1  1 0  1  0  0
c  d  0  0  0  1 1  1  1  0
e  f  1  0  1  0 0  1  0  0
```

and so on, the condition to extract data is, "if from column 3 to last column, the count of 0 is more than 4, it should not take that row into account"

the answer for above set will be:

```
a  b  1  0  1  1 0  1  0  0
c  d  0  0  0  1 1  1  1  0
```

Kindly help, I tried and failed.

Any thing in shell, python or PERL will do.

Thank you.

Comment: Please tell us what you tried - maybe some of your code would also be good!

Comment: since the occurence of 0 was is not ,limited to a certain column and it can occur in any column, the logic failed there itself. :(

Comment: aw, come on, the basic logic is very simple: read the line, sum the  tokens on it starting with the third; if the sum's more than 4, discard the row, else use it. Now with which part did you have a problem?

Comment: Closed as too localized? Really? What is it that is too localized about this question?

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

fin = open("text.txt","rb")
r = csv.reader(fin,delimiter="\t")
for line in r:
    if (sum(1 if x=='0' else 0 for x in line[3:]) < 4):
        print line
fin.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

If awk is acceptable, try:

```
awk '{
  c = x
  for (i = f - 1; ++i <= NF;)
    $i == 0 && c++
  }
c > l' l=4 f=3 infile
```

Given your file format, this may work too:

```
awk '{ r = $0 }
  gsub(/0/, x, r) > l
  ' l=4 infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example - written in Perl. Note, that you say "more than 4 zeros will not be taken into account" and actually are only taking rows with more than 4 zeros into account in your example output.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my ( $id1, $id2, @remaining_columns ) = split;
    my @zeros = grep { $_ == 0 } @remaining_columns;
    if ( @zeros > 4 ) {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
a  b  1  0  1  1 0  1  0  0
c  d  0  0  0  1 1  1  1  0
e  f  1  0  1  0 0  1  0  0
```

Comment: My fault ...wrong sample output

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that ignores any non numbers.....

```
line = "a b 2 1 2 2 3 2 3 2"

if (sum(map(int,filter(str.isdigit,line.split(" "))))) < 4:
    print line
```

Comment: oopps didn't read the question properly... thought it was that the total had to be less than 4....

Answer (score 1):

based on your **current** example (there is no 0 in 1st and 2nd columns).

awk:

```
awk '{x=$0;gsub(/[^0]/,"",x);}length(x)>4' yourFile
```

test:

```
kent$  echo "a  b  1  0  1  1 0  1  0  0
c  d  0  0  0  1 1  1  1  0
e  f  1  0  1  0 0  1  0  0
"|awk '{x=$0;gsub(/[^0]/,"",x);}length(x)>4'
```

output:

```
e  f  1  0  1  0 0  1  0  0
```

***also I feel confused, you want those lines number of 0 > 4 or <4???***

Comment: I have made the correction in the question. mistakenly wrong output was posted.

Comment: then you can just change ">" -> "<=" in my awk line.

Answer (score 1):

In (slightly) idiomatic Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  my (undef, undef, @cols) = split;
  print if (grep $_ == 0, @cols) > 4
}

__DATA__
a  b  1  0  1  1 0  1  0  0
c  d  0  0  0  1 1  1  1  0
e  f  1  0  1  0 0  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand the specification correctly, but you can adjust this as needed:

```
perl -ane 'print if 4 < grep 0 == $_, @F[2..$#F]'
```

Comment: `0 == $_` will give a false positive on non-numeric values.

Comment: @TLP: There are none in the example. Switch to `'0' eq $_` or whatever.

Comment: I was pondering how to do this safely and concisely when the question was closed.. What one could do is `grep !/\D/ && $_ == 0`, though that has drawbacks as well.

Answer (score 1):

Like Jan Hartung said, your description of the problem doesn't match the desired output, but if you want the rows with more than 4 zeros, this will do:

```
perl -ane 'print if grep(/^0$/,@F) > 4' data.tsv
```

I have assumed that the first and second column never contain 1s or 0s. If that's not the case, use `grep(/^0$/, @F[2..9])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different Perl solution using List::MoreUtils.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw/true/;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my ($ch1, $ch2, @arr) = split /\s+/, $line;
    print $line if ((true {$_ == 0} @arr) > 4);
}

__DATA__
a  b  1  0  1  1 0  1  0  0
c  d  0  0  0  1 1  1  1  0
e  f  1  0  1  0 0  1  0  0
```